# How do I quickly import the json file in the S3 bucket into AWS elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Current content:
1.Some json type file in S3 bucket. (About 3.7TB)
2.AWS Elasticsearch

Demand:
Import this json file to AWS Elasticsearch.

Current work:
1. At first, I thought that AWS provided such a feature, but when I looked at some information (Google Search, AWS public document), I did not find the shortcut function, what should I do to achieve this.

2.I want to analyze these json data, for example, the proportion of the content of a certain type, take out a certain type of value, is there a better solution besides AWS Elasticsearch? EMR or something else?